How and when vegetarianism in hinduism started
While looking for the reason why Hindu are vegetarian. i came to know there are lots of references in our text books which indicate in earlier times not all hindus were vegetarans
Below are some references
Rigveda 10.86.14: This hymn addresses the preparation and consumption of animal in the context of rituals.
Rigveda 10.91.14: In this verse, meat offerings in a yajna (sacrifice) are described, with reference to different kinds of food being offered, including meat
Rigveda 1.162 and 1.163: These hymns describe the Ashvamedha (horse sacrifice), a significant Vedic ritual in which the sacrificial horse was eventually consumed. The hymns describe how the horse is ceremonially prepared and then offered in the fire. The participants in the sacrifice, including priests and kings, would partake in consuming the meat of the sacrificed horse.
Manusmriti 5.30:
"The eater who eats the flesh of those to be eaten does nothing bad, even if he does it day after day; for God himself created some to be eaten and some to be eater."
Ramayana Ayodhya Kanda (Book 2, Chapter 20): When Rama is about to go into exile, his mother Kausalya expresses her concern that he might have to eat meat while living in the forest. She says:
"In the forest, you will have to live on fruits, roots, and meat."
Mahabarata:In Vana Parva (3.37.14) Bhima is described as hunting deer and other animals for food: "The mighty Bhima, bringing meat of various kinds, cooked it carefully and served it to his brothers."
Mahabarata:Adi Parva (Book 1, Chapter 206): In the Adi Parva, which deals with the early events of the epic, there are references to the Pandavas consuming meat as part of their royal feasts. During the marriage of Draupadi, Yudhishthira offers a grand feast to the assembled guests, which includes meat as part of the offerings.
Mahabarata Anushasana Parva (Book of Instructions): In this book, there is a discussion on the ethics of eating meat. Bhishma, while instructing Yudhishthira, acknowledges that meat-eating was permissible under certain circumstances, particularly for kshatriyas. However, he also extols the virtues of non-violence (ahimsa) and vegetarianism.
now the question is if above is the case when hindus started turning to vegetarians?
specailly some hindus do not eat meat on specific days (example some hindus do not eat meat on tuesdays // i did not found any reference for that in our texts)
Any insight would be helpful

Animals killed in yajna and offered at the time of Sraddha were allowed to be consumed in the previous yugas but banned in Kali Yuga.
